# Leetcode Linked List II question No. 142.Wrong Solution but why does it work?

Tags: c, malloc, singly-linked-list

This is the code that I wrote in leetcode I know that the implementation of this is wrong but why does this work?

```
struct ListNode *detectCycle(struct ListNode *head) {
    struct ListNode *cur = head;

    while(cur){
        if(cur >= cur->next) return cur->next;
        
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

This code should not have worked right? this should be the ideal solution

```
struct ListNode *fastp = head , *slowp = head;
        if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
            return NULL;

        struct ListNode *slow = head;
        struct ListNode *fast = head;
        struct ListNode *entry = head;

        while(fast->next && fast->next->next){
            slow = slow->next;
            fast = fast->next->next;
            if(slow == fast){ 
                while(slow != entry){
                    slow = slow->next;
                    entry = entry->next;
                }
                return entry;
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

In other ways it can always be expressed as why are all the nodes always malloced with less address than before?

Comment: You got lucky. Not a behavior to count on.

Comment: Perhaps the nodes have been allocated as an array, and then linked together. I've seen this done in academic/contest environments before.

Comment: Is it really wrong if it passed all the test cases?

Comment: @Shawn If this code passed all the test cases, the problem is with the test cases.

Comment: "works" != "predictably works"

Comment: @Barmar leetcode has many problems yes (my big peeve is that whoever puts together the Racket test cases has apparently never heard of vectors). And this code would be badly broken in probably any other environment. But for competitive programming type stuff, passing the tests without timing out is what's important. As long as OP recognizes that it's not a suitable approach for real world code....

Comment: Indeed. This is really "Why does the leetcode validator pass this obviously broken code?" And that's not really a good SO question.

Answer (score 1):

The faulty code assumes that the memory addresses of the distinct nodes increase as the list is traversed. Relying on the addresses of the allocated nodes in the list is of course wrong. If all test cases pass, this means the test cases allocated memory in a way that allows this logic to give the correct answer. For instance, if the nodes were allocated in the same order as they were added to the list, it is much more likely that the memory addresses of consecutive nodes increase, than that this would not be the case.

Here is a test case that is likely to produce the wrong result with the faulty code: it creates a linked list 1→2→3→4→5→2 (where there is only one node with value 2). But the allocation of nodes happens in a different order, with node 2 allocated *last*.

Assume the wrong function is called `detectCycleWrong` and the correct implementation is called `detectCycleCorrect`, then try running the above described test case:

```
    struct ListNode *one = createNode(1);
    struct ListNode *three = createNode(3);
    struct ListNode *four = createNode(4);
    struct ListNode *five = createNode(5);
    // Allocated last: the node that will close the cycle
    struct ListNode *two = createNode(2);
 
    one->next = two;
    two->next = three;
    three->next = four;
    four->next = five;
    five->next = two;  // Back link
    
    struct ListNode *resultCorrect = detectCycleCorrect(one);
    printf("cycle at: %d\n", resultCorrect ? resultCorrect->val : -1);  // 2
    
    struct ListNode *resultWrong = detectCycleWrong(one);
    printf("cycle at: %d\n", resultWrong ? resultWrong->val : -1);  // 3?
```

The correct implementation will output 2, but the faulty implementation is quite likely (but not guaranteed) to output 3.

Comment: You could guarantee particular results by creating an array of nodes and then arranging their `next` pointers to point to specific indexes.

Comment: Nothing says "useless in the real world" like a linked list where all of the nodes are sequentially laid out in an array.